# Multiply movieclip's content as if dragging corners?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

When you put your mouse on the corner of an image, you can drag it and the image will be multiplied depending on how much you drag the mouse.  Is it possible to do this through code?  For example, I lay my mouse on the corner of a movieclip and see a square cursor next to my mouse.  Now I drag and the image duplicates a bit.  Like a perspective transform?

Comment: Do you mean when you drag a file on your PC there is a ghosting effect where a transparent version of the icon is attached the cursor? Also you've tagged both AS2 and AS3 - which one are you intending to use?

Comment: No, like when you put an image to the stage and press 'break apart' you can drag the corners and image will get not larger but will grow more of itself or you can hide part of it by dragging it in the direction in which you are grabbing it.

Comment: You mean you want to create a shape with ActionScript and fill it with an image so that it repeats?

Comment: @Marty Wallace Kind of, when you drag a movieclip's corner you're doing a perspective transform in which the movieclip repeats as you drag, I'd like to do that in actionscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.beginBitmapFill()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginBitmapFill%28%29)

Here's a demo:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ready);
loader.load( new URLRequest("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/") );

function ready(e:Event):void
{
    var shape:Shape = new Shape();

    shape.x = shape.y = 50;
    shape.graphics.beginBitmapFill((loader.content as Bitmap).bitmapData);

    shape.graphics.lineTo(100, 0);
    shape.graphics.lineTo(60, 120);
    shape.graphics.lineTo(-30, 50);
    shape.graphics.lineTo(0, 0);
    shape.graphics.endFill();

    addChild(shape);
}
```

Comment: Umm. no, just drawRect where you have the topLeft corner of the image and the drag square's x/y. also do startDrag on the cursor so it moves with the mouse. Make sure the fill type of the bitmapFill does your desired effect, I can't remember if its defaulted in a tiled type.